# adding image on a panel

Tags: java, image, animation, panel, sprite

uhhmm. ive been finding ways on adding images(Image object) on a panel. Basically, what i want to do is to create a page - a panel with moving objects (animation using sprites). but i can't. everytime i try to add the images to the panel, the screen goes on like "blinking". anyone can help me with this? I need this ASAP.. thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Any hint of the language/tool?

Comment: Phil, sorry for the late reply. i'm using Java for this project. I'm really at lost with sprites. i managed to get some images moving, but i can't add listeners to them. do you have ideas on this?

Comment: Are you having a problem with animating images or with adding listeners? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess here, but it sounds like the ubiquitous vertical sync problem experienced in any animated graphical endeavour. In some languages you have to engage a 'double buffer' to correct this. Your panel might have such a property.